# Google calendar reminders

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api

I have a Laravel 5 project and I create event on google calendar with [larvael-google-calendar](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar).

I need to create reminder but not reminder of an event (so not the notifications to remind an event). The reminder you can create on Google calendar.

This :

[image]

Which look like this after created :

[image]

And not this

[image]

But I don't find anything on it, when I research I always find results concerning the reminder like a notification.

Anybody know how to create it with the API or another method (PHP of course)? (I don't care if I need to remove my package, just want a solution).

Comment: The reminders you are speaking of are not part of google calendar and there is no api to add them the best you can do is create an event

Comment: @DaImTo
Thanks for your answer ! You can post it like an answer if you want and I will validate it.
I was thinking it's not possible because I can't find anything so you confirm it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually looked around for this for a long time.  This is the conclusion i have come to.

The reminders you are speaking of arnt actually part of Google Calendar they are more part of your full Google account as far as i have been able to tell.

You can for example create a reminder though the Google assistant, Google Calendar android app and the Gmail android app as far as i have seen so far.

It appears that this works across multiple applications there for IMO this is not directly part of Google calendar and thats why we cant seem to find an option for adding remainders from within the Google Calendar api.

I think we will have to wait for Google to release a new API for this.

Comment: @DalmTo

This post is a few years old. Safe to assume we're still waiting?

Comment: Seems it hasn't happened yet. Found an official feature request, posting link here.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760283